# Correcting spelling mistakes in posts

Tags: feature-request, editing

Edits to posts (questions anyway) need to be at least 6 characters. Correcting spelling mistakes is justifiable reason to edit a post. Many corrections of spelling mistakes require less than 6 characters to carry out the edit. As a result it is not possible to correct some spelling mistakes without adding additional content to the author's post.

Can this be changed, and what considerations against making this change are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [edit privileges](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) page says, "Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged."

There are a lot of questions out there that could be made substantially better, particularly in the tags, so it's better to direct your energy elsewhere.

Comment: A good point. In the specific example that I had in mind the wrong word had been entered, and such instances could cause confusion. 

As you point out though, perhaps it is better to focus attention elsewhere, and if it really is that big of an issue then a more substantial edit could be made.